# Spark 2.0 memory fraction

Tags: memory, apache-spark, out-of-memory, distributed-computing, apache-spark-2.0

I am working with Spark 2.0, the job starts by sorting the input data and storing its output on HDFS.

I was getting out of memory errors, the solution was to increase the value of "spark.shuffle.memoryFraction" from 0.2 to 0.8 and this solved the problem. But in the documentation I have found that this is a deprecated parameter.

As I understand, it was replaced by "spark.memory.fraction". How to modify this parameter while taking into account the sort and storage on HDFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview):

> Although there are two relevant configurations, the typical user
> should not need to adjust them as the default values are applicable to
> most workloads:
>
> - `spark.memory.fraction` expresses the size of M as a fraction of the    (JVM heap space - 300MB) (default 0.6). The rest of the space (40%)
>   is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and
>   safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually
>   large records.
> - `spark.memory.storageFraction` expresses the size of R as a fraction of    M (default 0.5). R is the storage space within M where cached
>   blocks    immune to being evicted by execution.
>
> The value of `spark.memory.fraction` should be set in order to fit this
> amount of heap space comfortably within the JVM’s old or “tenured”
> generation. Otherwise, when much of this space is used for caching and
> execution, the tenured generation will be full, which causes the JVM
> to significantly increase time spent in garbage collection.

In [spark-1.6.2](/questions/tagged/spark-1.6.2) I would modify the `spark.storage.memoryFraction`.

---

As a side note, are you sure that you understand how your job behaves?

It's typical to fine tune your job starting from the `memoryOverhead`, #cores , etc. firstly and then move on to the attribute you modified.

Comment: The rest of the space (25%) should be The rest of the space (40%) ?

Comment: Guess it changed from the time posted @shuailiu, thanks, post updated!